# Get customer with same payment for 2 different account types in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to get the final payment for a customer same payment key for 2 different account types with the same amount paid in the SQL Server?

```
SELECT  
    p.Amount,
    t.date, 
    p.PayKey,
    t.BillKey 
FROM
    Transaction t
INNER JOIN 
    payment p ON t.PayKey = p.PayKey
LEFT JOIN
    BillTable b ON t.BillKey = b.Sbillkey 
                AND t.Tbillkey = b.BillKey 
WHERE   
    t.BillKey in (123457, 1786243)
```

My results

```
Amount       date      PayKey   BillKey
----------------------------------------
2540.00     2020-02-06  762944   123457
2540.00     2020-02-06  762944  1786243
```

But the final results I would like to obtain is :

```
Amount       date      PayKey   
-------------------------------
2540.00     2020-02-06  762944
```

Comment: please share table structure and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Group By`.

```
SELECT  
    p.Amount,
    t.date, 
    p.PayKey 
FROM
    Transaction t
INNER JOIN 
    payment p ON t.PayKey = p.PayKey
LEFT JOIN
    BillTable b ON t.BillKey = b.Sbillkey 
                AND t.Tbillkey = b.BillKey 
WHERE   
    t.BillKey in (123457, 1786243)
GROUP BY 
    p.Amount,
    t.date, 
    p.PayKey
```

Or use `Distinct` to return unique rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.Amount,
    t.date, 
    p.PayKey 
FROM
    Transaction t
INNER JOIN 
    payment p ON t.PayKey = p.PayKey
LEFT JOIN
    BillTable b ON t.BillKey = b.Sbillkey 
                AND t.Tbillkey = b.BillKey 
WHERE   
    t.BillKey in (123457, 1786243)
```

Comment: the group by works but not the distinct

Comment: A `DISTINCT` will make the result unique on the row level. So it should return only 1 `(2540.00, '2020-02-06', 762944)` tupple.

Comment: Does `Transaction.date` have the DATE datatype? And is `Payment.PayKey` a DECIMAL datatype?

Comment: Yes they are. But the amount is currency, would you still do a group by on the currency field without aggregate ?

Comment: I don't know. Only you have access to your data. And to be honest, I find it a bit odd that both tables have 2 *billkey columns.

Comment: At least if it's a money datatype, then the currency doesn't matter in the group by or distinct.  Test [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f5d07cc0bf340e56fd703bdeb22be70b)